# docker for php5.3 on centos image

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, centos7, php-5.3

I want to run legacy php 5.3 apps on centos 7. Since there is no php 5.3 build on centos 7, docker container looks like a preferred option. 
I referred to this [article](https://www.prosinger.net/php-5-3-centos-7/) to build a docker container but I am unable to access the php web pages from port 9003 in local host. The following are places where I may need help.

1. There was an issue with using sockets in line 1 of the script, so I just deleted this line
2. The container runs fine but when I run localhost:9003 on the browser I am not able to serve php pages from /var/www/html

I want to have apache and php files on local and only want to run php on the container..

help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

> The container runs fine but when I run localhost:9003 on the browser I
>   am not able to serve php pages from /var/www/html

You need to expose the ports by adding `-p 9003:9003` to the run command.

Answer (score 0):

Try run docker with network parameter like `--network=<NETWORK>`. looking for available network use command `docker network ls`.

i advise to use the bridge network mode:

`docker --network=bridge`